# How do you create a Postgresql database on a Windows system?

Tags: postgresql, installation, pgadmin

I installed Postgresql and have `pgAdmin III` running.

I'm following the instructions in the [Postgres doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/postmaster-start.html) on how to get my database started, but I'm not having luck with the first line.

Typing `postmaster` into my `cmd` is returning

```
not recognized...
```

It seems this command is only for Linux or Mac machines.

Does anyone know how to apply these instructions to Windows? Or if a manual for Windows exists? (Googling has turned up nothing useful)

Comment: You do it in sql shell not in cmd.Check your postgres folder in programs

Comment: Connect to the database and run `create database`. See the manual for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html  You should never, ever run `postmaster.exe` or `postgres.exe` directly. Postgres is usually started through a service on Windows. And don't read the manual for an **completely** outdated version.  Use the manual for *your* version.

Comment: Open pgAdmin, connect to your postgres-server (running local) using the default database "postgres" and create a new database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed PostgreSQL from the EnterpriseDB distribution then the postmaster is already running as a service. You can check this from the Control Panel (Administrative Tools | Services). Can you connect to your local installation using pgAdmin III? If so, then you are all set. In pgAdmin III, connect to the local server, then on the Databases node in the tree under the server select 'New database...'.